# What have to do with the desktop environment?

Tags: desktop-environments

The story is: I'm trying Linux for the first time in my life. I'm encountering problems and I need to know what of them are responsibility of who. some of them are particular applications bugs, for example the calculator says 1+1=0 (I know that's very absurd, is a exaggeration to make the point). Others seem to be deeper and to have to do the system, but I can't separate the Desktop environment, Gnome in my case, from the Linux OS, such as Ubuntu or Mint.
Can you tell me exactly what tasks the Desktop environments do in Linux?

If more appropriate, you can move my question to Unix and Linux.

IMPORTANT EDIT: THIS QUESTION SHOULD TOTALLY BE DELETED TO CLEAN, it is VERY unuseful now for me or for everyone, I needed to resolve a doubt and the answer I accepted it's very not-useful for everyone who reads it.
I haven't deleted because doing so, according to the site, will affect me negatively in regards of being able to ask questions, because I will be deleting an question who has already an accepted answer.

Comment: If that app came with Gnome, you should report the bugs on launchpad.  Desktop can be separated from Ubuntu. In fact it is possible to get other desktops. For instance, I am on Ubuntu 14.04 using Blackbox right now

Comment: @Serg That does not answer the main point.

Comment: That wasn't inteded to be an answer, merely a comment. Also, what exactly is your main point ? Please make it clear so that it's easier for people to answer

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP said so. Otherwise it should be improved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My interpretation of your questions it that you are wondering what the desktop environment does, and how it could be related to your application bugs. If that's incorrect, please clarify your question and/or comment on my answer.

The desktop environment in Linux allows user to manipulate their computer graphically, as is done on Mac OS X and Windows. Different desktop environments have look and feel different, provide different functionality, and sometimes come with their own applications (i.e. the Gnome Calculator).

The bug that you are referencing is most likely not a bug, but rather the system is confused somewhere, and I would advise you to just reboot your computer, as that should probably fix it. If that doesn't fix it, submit a bug report to [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/~gnome3-team).

Please mark this as `Answered` if this helped, if not, please clarify your question.